# FMX + Android + Rotation

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Trying to determine a "180° flip": [all of the above methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862569/how-do-i-detect-handle-a-screen-rotate-using-firemonkey-for-delphi-xe5) are useless when the device is quickly flipped (for example from "Landscape" to "Reverse landscape")

But there is a "native way" — through the [OrientationEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26235708/2689204). Can anyone help make it work?

```
unit android.view.OrientationEventListener;

interface

uses
  AndroidAPI.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;

type
  JOrientationEventListener = interface;

  JOrientationEventListenerClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{6C04CBB1-63B1-45E1-9CBE-AE3F41A60064}']
    function _GetORIENTATION_UNKNOWN: Integer; cdecl;
    function canDetectOrientation : boolean; cdecl;
    function init(context: JContext): JOrientationEventListener; cdecl; overload;
    function init(context: JContext; rate: Integer): JOrientationEventListener; cdecl; overload;
    procedure disable; cdecl;
    procedure enable; cdecl;
    procedure onOrientationChanged(Integerparam0: integer); cdecl;
    property ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN : Integer read _GetORIENTATION_UNKNOWN;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/view/OrientationEventListener')]
  JOrientationEventListener = interface(JObject)
    ['{ED4F435E-E48F-420E-A26E-75BFB8FCCB94}']
    function canDetectOrientation: boolean; cdecl;
    procedure disable; cdecl;
    procedure enable; cdecl;
    procedure onOrientationChanged(Integerparam0: integer); cdecl;
  end;

  TJOrientationEventListener = class(TJavaGenericImport<JOrientationEventListenerClass, JOrientationEventListener>)
  end;

const
  TJOrientationEventListenerORIENTATION_UNKNOWN = -1;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: How do you know that implementing an Orientation listener won't be just as "useless" as a MessengerManger Message handler? What is meant by the word "useless"?

Comment: >How do you know that implementing an Orientation listener won't be just as "useless" as a MessengerManger Message handler?

Let's try and find out ;)

>What is meant by the word "useless"?
"Unhelpful, not useful; pointless (of an action)" ;)
https://s3.gifyu.com/images/1595987709ea73fdaf.gif (~12MB)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started looking into creating a descendant of OrientationEventListener (which presently can be done only in Java code), however that came with its own set of problems, namely that the [canDetectOrientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener#canDetectOrientation()) function would always return false!

Next up I looked into why the [TOrientationChangedMessage](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Forms.TOrientationChangedMessage) was not being sent when changing immediately from "normal" to "inverted" orientation - that appears to be because the [onConfigurationChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onconfigurationchanged) method is not being called on the activity (i.e. no way Delphi can help this)

I figured then that perhaps the easiest way is to use a timer (ugh) to check when the screen rotation changes, so I came up with the following [unit which is now in the Kastri repo](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/blob/master/Core/DW.OrientationMonitor.pas):

```
unit DW.OrientationMonitor;

{*******************************************************}
{                                                       }
{                      Kastri                           }
{                                                       }
{         Delphi Worlds Cross-Platform Library          }
{                                                       }
{  Copyright 2020-2021 Dave Nottage under MIT license   }
{  which is located in the root folder of this library  }
{                                                       }
{*******************************************************}

{$I DW.GlobalDefines.inc}

interface

uses
  // FMX
  FMX.Types;

type
  TOrientationChangedEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; const Orientation: TScreenOrientation) of object;

  TOrientationMonitor = class(TObject)
  private
    FHasOrientationChanged: Boolean;
    FOrientation: TScreenOrientation;
    FRotation: Integer;
    FTimer: TTimer;
    FOnOrientationChanged: TOrientationChangedEvent;
    procedure DoOrientationChange;
    procedure SetIsActive(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure TimerHandler(Sender: TObject);
    function GetIsActive: Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property IsActive: Boolean read GetIsActive write SetIsActive;
    property Orientation: TScreenOrientation read FOrientation;
    property OnOrientationChanged: TOrientationChangedEvent read FOnOrientationChanged write FOnOrientationChanged;
  end;

implementation

uses
  // DW
  DW.UIHelper;

{ TOrientationMonitor }

constructor TOrientationMonitor.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FOrientation := TUIHelper.GetScreenOrientation;
  FTimer := TTimer.Create(nil);
  FTimer.Interval := 100;
  FTimer.OnTimer := TimerHandler;
end;

destructor TOrientationMonitor.Destroy;
begin
  FTimer.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TOrientationMonitor.DoOrientationChange;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnOrientationChanged) then
    FOnOrientationChanged(Self, FOrientation);
end;

function TOrientationMonitor.GetIsActive: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FTimer.Enabled;
end;

procedure TOrientationMonitor.SetIsActive(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  FTimer.Enabled := Value;
end;

procedure TOrientationMonitor.TimerHandler(Sender: TObject);
var
  LOrientation: TScreenOrientation;
begin
  LOrientation := TUIHelper.GetScreenOrientation;
  if LOrientation <> FOrientation then
  begin
    FOrientation := LOrientation;
    DoOrientationChange;
  end;
end;

end.
```

**NOTE** The unit relies on other units in the Kastri repo, but you could just as well extract the `GetScreenOrientation` method

An example of using `TOrientationMonitor`:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls,
  DW.OrientationMonitor;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
  private
    FOrientation: TScreenOrientation;
    FOrientationMonitor: TOrientationMonitor;
    procedure OrientationChangedHandler(Sender: TObject; const AOrientation: TScreenOrientation);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
  System.TypInfo;

{ TForm1 }

constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FOrientationMonitor := TOrientationMonitor.Create;
  FOrientationMonitor.OnOrientationChanged := OrientationChangedHandler;
  FOrientation := FOrientationMonitor.Orientation;
  Label1.Text := Format('Orientation: %s', [GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TScreenOrientation), Ord(FOrientation))]);
  FOrientationMonitor.IsActive := True;
end;

destructor TForm1.Destroy;
begin
  FOrientationMonitor.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.OrientationChangedHandler(Sender: TObject; const AOrientation: TScreenOrientation);
var
  LInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  LInfo := TypeInfo(TScreenOrientation);
  Label1.Text := Format('Old: %s, New: %s', [GetEnumName(LInfo, Ord(FOrientation)), GetEnumName(LInfo, Ord(AOrientation))]);
  FOrientation := AOrientation;
end;

end.
```

During this investigation I discovered that the test app would not rotate into the inverted portrait position. The trick to making it so that it does is by updating the manifest to include the `android:screenOrientation` attribute with a value of `fullSensor` into the `activity` node, like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
        android:label="%activityLabel%"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question about OrientationEventListener, but I hope it'll achieve what you desire